# Ruby Interpolation Search on 2nd Element of a Two Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array, linear-interpolation

What I have below is a simple interpolation search on a single dimensional array `$employee_list`. The list is an ordered list of employees' id that might have gaps due to retirements.

```
def exist?(id)
  lower = 0
  upper = $employee_list.length - 1
  while $employee_list[upper] != $employee_list[lower] && id >= $employee_list[lower] && id <= $employee_list[upper]
      middle = lower + ((id - $employee_list[lower]) * (upper - lower) / ($employee_list[upper] - $employee_list[lower]))
      if id > $employee_list[middle]
        lower = middle + 1
      elsif id < $employee_list[middle]
        upper = middle - 1
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  return false
end
```

Now I want to add a new element to the list and the 2nd element of the array will contain the employee birth year (i.e. `$employee_list[id][birthyear]`). I am able to sort the array based on the birthyear and I would like to perform a interpolation search based on the birthyear and return the list of employee ids that have that particular birthyear.

Comment: It would be very useful if you posted an input (an example of your `employee_list` variable) and the desired output

Comment: @Bustikiller a sample element in the $employee_list array would be [19, 1992]. It means employee with id 19 is born on 1992. And also the return value of the method should be an array that contains the id of all the employees born on a selected year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version. It returns **one** `id` if an employee with given year has been found, and `nil` if no employee has been found.

You'll need a modified version of interpolation search if you need to return multiple ids for a year. Finally, interpolation search works best with uniformly distributed values. I guess it's really not the case for birthyear of employees.

```
def find_id_for_year(array, year)
  lower = 0
  upper = array.length - 1
  while array[upper][1] != array[lower][1] && year >= array[lower][1]  && year <= array[upper][1]
    middle = lower + ((year - array[lower][1]) * (upper - lower) / (array[upper][1] - array[lower][1]))
    if year > array[middle][1]
      lower = middle + 1
    elsif year < array[middle][1]
      upper = middle - 1
    else
      return array[middle][0]
    end
  end
end

employee_list = Array.new(10) {|i| [i, rand(1990..2000)] }.sort_by(&:last)

p employee_list
#=> [[5, 1990], [8, 1990], [2, 1991], [9, 1991], [7, 1992], [0, 1995], [6, 1996], [4, 1998], [1, 1999], [3, 1999]]
#=> [[8, 1990], [4, 1991], [5, 1991], [6, 1991], [2, 1996], [0, 1998], [1, 1998], [3, 1998], [7, 1999], [9, 2000]]

p find_id_for_year(employee_list, 1992)
#=> 7
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the following `employee_list`:

```
employee_list = [[19, 1992], [41, 1985], [12, 1958], [63, 1985]]
```

If you want to get the `ids` of the employees born in 1985 you just need to select those arrays whose last element is 1985, and get the first element of the filtered arrays:

```
employee_list.select{|employee| employee.last == 1985}.map(&:first)
# => [41, 63]
```